# I can't figure out how to arrange these buttons as seen in the link

Tags: java, button, user-interface, layout, gridbaglayout

```
package GUI;

import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GridBagLayoutEx2
{
     public GridBagLayoutEx2()
    {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagLayoutEx2");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    JButton b1 = new JButton("1");
    JButton b2 = new JButton("2");
    JButton b3 = new JButton("3");
    JButton b4 = new JButton("4");
    JButton b5 = new JButton("5");

    gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridheight = 5;
    gbc.gridwidth = 3;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    panel.add(b1, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    panel.add(b2, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    panel.add(b3, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 3;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    panel.add(b4, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 4;
    gbc.gridwidth = 3;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    panel.add(b5, gbc);

    frame.add(panel);
    //frame.pack();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GridBagLayoutEx2();
}

}
```

[image]

Hello to everyone. I have been trying to settle this GUI for a while. Eventhough I watched many GUI tutorials, after countless number of trial-and-errors I gave up. In image (above) you can see the layout I am trying make. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Without any code we are not going to be able to help you

Comment: If you use an AbsoluteLayout, you can manually specify the coordinates of each button.  It's more work, but it will get you the exact layout you are looking for.  Try reading here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html

Comment: @MichaelParker that link says _you should use a layout manager if at all possible_

Comment: @Reimeus Which is why I posted that as a comment, and not an answer.

Comment: I would prefer using something like GridBag. However got stuck

Comment: Well first of all, your illustrations places 6 buttons in the layout, while in your code you only declare 5 :p

Comment: code is just for a hint

Comment: @MichaelParker Absolute layouts introduce about 1000% more work, as you know become responsible for the job the layout manager was doing for you, including resizing the components in response to changes in the parent container as well as responding to changes in the child components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `MigLayout` manager. For the unit type, I have chosen centimeters.
`MigLayout` provides several unit types to choose from.

The following example fits your image well:

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class ButtonsEx extends JFrame {

    public ButtonsEx() {

        initUI();

        setTitle("MigLayout example");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new MigLayout());
        pnl.add(new JButton("Button"), "spany 2, grow, w 4cm, h 4cm");
        pnl.add(new JButton("Button"), "spanx 2, w 4cm, h 2cm, grow");
        pnl.add(new JButton("Button"), "w 2cm, h 2cm, wrap");
        pnl.add(new JButton("Button"), "w 2cm, h 2cm");
        pnl.add(new JButton("Button"), "w 2cm, h 2cm");
        pnl.add(new JButton("Button"), "w 2cm, h 2cm, wrap");

        add(pnl);

        pack();
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ButtonsEx ex = new ButtonsEx();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: MigLayout example]

Comment: thanks, haven't imported that Mig stuff, but it just looks right